# Cannot convert Char and Int HashMap to a string

Tags: java

I've been trying to figure out how to convert all of the elements (both keys and values) to a string. The result should look something like "a2b3c4" for example.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main{
  public static String stringCompression(String s){

    s = s.toLowerCase();
    HashMap<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (map.containsKey(c)){
        map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
    }
    else{
      map.put(c, 1);
    }
  }

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
  for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++){
    sb.append(map.get(i));
  }
  
  return sb.toString();

  }

  public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println(stringCompression("aabccccaaa"));
    System.out.println(stringCompression("abc"));
    System.out.println(stringCompression("AabBcCdDdDDeE"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your expected output for each of your three example inputs.

Comment: Use proper indenting to make your example code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

`map.get( i )` is incorrect. Your keys are `Character` objects, not the `int i` used in your loop.

Call `Map#keySet`, and loop those key objects rather than incrementing an `int i`. Replace your `for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++){` with `for ( Character key : map.keySet() )`

## Details

By the way, you use the word "compression" but what you are doing is not compression. You are counting *total* repetition of each character, rather than counting each series of a repeated character separately.

Your code for populating the map is correct. We can see that by doing a `println` to see the map’s contents. For input `"aabccccaaa"` we get this map: `map.toString(): {a=5, b=1, c=4}`.

The problem is where you build up text with `StringBuilder`. You call `map.get( i )`. This means you are asking for the value mapped to a key of 0, 1, 2, and such. But you are not using integer numbers as your key. You are using `Character` as your key type.

Instead, you should be looping on the set of all keys. Then do a `get` for each of those keys. Your `StringBuilder` code should look like this:

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Set < Character > keys = map.keySet();
for ( Character key : keys )
{
    Integer count = map.get( key );
    sb.append( key ).append( count );
}
```

By the way, your insertions into the map could be made into a single line of call by using [`Map#merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) method. So this:

```java
    if (map.containsKey(c)){
        map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
    }
    else{
      map.put(c, 1);
    }
```

…becomes this:

```java
map.merge( c , 1 , Integer :: sum );
```

The `Integer :: sum` is a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). A method reference is an object that *represents* that method rather than *calls* that method. The `merge` method will call that `sum` method while performing its work.

By the way, your line `s = s.toLowerCase();` replaces the passed argument `String` object with a new `String` object. I do not recommend this. You have discarded the original text with nothing gained. You have tossed valuable information needed for debugging and logging. Instead, define a new `String` variable: `String input = s.toLowerCase();`. And to prevent such re-assignment of the argument variable, mark the argument declaration as `final`.

Complete code example:

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class RepeatCounter
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( countCharacterOccurrence( "aabccccaaa" ) );
        System.out.println( countCharacterOccurrence( "abc" ) );
        System.out.println( countCharacterOccurrence( "AabBcCdDdDDeE" ) );
    }

    public static String countCharacterOccurrence ( final String s )
    {

        String input = s.toLowerCase();
        HashMap < Character, Integer > map = new HashMap <>();

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++ )
        {
            char c = input.charAt( i );
            map.merge( c , 1 , Integer :: sum );
        }
        // System.out.println( "map = " + map );

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Set < Character > keys = map.keySet();
        for ( Character key : keys )
        {
            Integer count = map.get( key );
            sb.append( key ).append( count );
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

When run.

```
a5b1c4
a1b1c1
a2b2c2d5e2
```

---

You may want to use another [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) implementation rather than [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html). The `HashMap` class makes no promise as to the iteration order of its keys.

If you want the keys kept in sorted order, use a `SortedMap`/[`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) implementation such as [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html).

If you want the keys kept in their original insertion order, use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Here is a graphic table I made of the `Map` implementations bundled with Java.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

---

By the way, the `char`/`Character` type in Java is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the 143,859 characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

While your code can handle an input of "Hello World", it will fail with an input of "Hello  world ️".

Learn to use integer [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) numbers instead. So your Map would be a `Map < Integer , Integer >` where the first `Integer` represents the code point number of each character, and the second `Integer` is the count of its occurrences.

For more info, read: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: this is very helpful, thank you so much for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done conveniently using Stream API:

1. Prepare frequency map
2. Convert map entries to String
3. Join strings without delimiter

```java
public static String stringCompression(String s) {
    return s.toLowerCase().chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char)c)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.summingInt(c -> 1)))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> e.getKey() + Integer.toString(e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Test:

```java
System.out.println(stringCompression("aabccccaaa"));
System.out.println(stringCompression("abc"));
System.out.println(stringCompression("AabBcCdDdDDeE"));
```

Output:

```
a5b1c4
a1b1c1
a2b2c2d5e2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Issues

1. Unfortunately, using a map will not give the correct to your question.
2. If you accumulate the complete string and add to Map, then you will add same character across different parts into same key
3. This will result in incorrect solution
4. Incorrect: ex: `aaabbbaaa` -> `a6b3` (assuming you use LinkedHashMap)
5. The actual output should be `a3b3a3`

### Code as per Question

```java
  map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> String.valueOf(e.getKey()) + e.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.joining(""))
```

### Run Length Encoding: A possible (still inefficient compression) solution

1. Iterate over characters from left to right
2. combine any adjacent similar characters along with count
3. This does not compress subpatterns

```java
    public static String compress(String str) {
        if (str == null || str.length() < 3) {
            return str;
        }
        char[] input = str.toCharArray();
        int left = 0;
        char state = input[0];

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int right = 1; right < input.length; right++) {
            final char candidate = input[right];
            // on mismatch add the previously noted character
            if (state != candidate) {
                if (right - left > 1) {
                    builder.append(state).append(right - left);
                } else {
                    builder.append(state);
                }
                // watch the current character
                left = right;
                state = candidate;
            }
        }
        // add the last unique character
        builder.append(state);
        if (input.length - left > 1) {
            builder.append(input.length - left);
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        compress("abc"); // abc
        compress("aabbc"); // a2b2c
        compress("aabbcaabbc"); // a2b2ca2b2c actually this should be (a2b2c)2

    }
```

Comment: @AlexRudenko, apologies for the careless example, it should be `a3b3a3`. Thank you reporting